# Sharing violation on program-generated xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a C# console application using monodevelop, and I recently decided to use an xml file as way of storing user preferences. Creating, writing the initial data, and reading the file are easily accomplished, and from what I've seen updating it should be too. However, the code below generates a Sharing violation on path:

```
public void Update (string username, PreferenceAttribute preferencename, string newvalue)
    {
        try 
        {
            ...
            //this is where it throws exception \/
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream (filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                string attribute = preferencename.ToString ();
                doc = new XmlDocument ();
                doc.Load (fs);
                fs.Close ();
                XmlNode user = doc.SelectSingleNode ("//Users/User[@Name = '" + username + "']");
                XmlNode pref = user.SelectSingleNode("Pref");
                pref.Attributes[attribute].Value = newvalue;
                doc.Save (fs);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error details output
        }
    }
```

Leaving out the using block causes the error to happen at the doc.save(fs) line and also results in the file losing any data it had. I've looked at other posts, but the only solutions seem to be the using block. I need a way to get the lock on the file (unless my code is generating the problem). Any help?

Edit: here is the xml document I'm trying to edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Do not modify this auto-generated file. Doing so will cause unwanted behavior. If modification causes problems, delete this file and rerun the program-->
<Users>
  <User Name="Ben" Password="hello54">
    <Pref Gender="Male" Admin="false" Butler="Alfred" Eastereggs="false" />
  </User>
  <User Name="Admin" Password="admin">
    <Pref Gender="Male" Admin="true" Butler="Butler" Eastereggs="false" />
  </User>
</Users>
```

I recognize that storing passwords and things in this way is unsafe; however, I'm an amateur trying to learn about xml and develop my C# skills, so for the time being it's ok.

Stacktrace:

```
Sharing violation on path /Users/Knoble/MonoProjects/Test_Console/Test_Console/bin/Debug/Preferences.xml
mscorlib
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x0032f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.10.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-3.10.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.10.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-3.10.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:132 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at XMLPref.XMLPreferences.Update (System.String username, PreferenceAttribute preferencename, System.String newvalue) [0x0003d] in /Users/Knoble/MonoProjects/Test_Console/XMLPreferences/XMLPreferences.cs:299 
Void .ctor(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, Boolean, FileOptions)
```

Comment: Why do you close the stream in the middle of working with it?

Comment: When I first started researching this problem, one of the solutions that lead me to the using block recommended this (I think because the XmlDocument takes over the stream and creates its own?). I'm not entirely sure this is the problem though since the stack trace shows the error occurring in the line with the using statement.

Comment: @BenKnoble: Can you provide the stacktrace? It is possible it shows the error in the `using` block because at the end of such block, the stream will be `Close`d a second time.

Comment: @CommuSoft Here it is:

Comment: @BenKnoble: perhaps update the question with the stacktrace... I don't think comments are used for this.

Comment: yeah hit enter on accident

Comment: @BenKnoble: is it possible that your program by any chance already opened the file somewhere else and failed to close it? Furthermore I guess if you ask `Write` access to a file, you can't allow `FileAccess.Read` at the same time.

Comment: Its possible but im fairly certain i closed.

Comment: @BenKnoble: I've provided an answer. I think the main problem is that you allow both `FileAccess.ReadWrite` (with `Write`) and `FileSharing.Read`. Some OSs (if not all) won't allow this because other programs can read corrupt data.

Comment: As an aside, if someone could point me to a good way to append a new user to this file, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.

If you ask write access to your file (`FileAccess.ReadWrite`), you can't allow other streams/threads/programs to read (`FileShare.Read`) it at the same time.

The problem is that once you `Close` a `Stream` (e.g. a `FileStream`, you can't read/write to it anymore). You give the OS a signal that the file can now be used by other programs.

A potential solution to the problem is using the file twice:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream (filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
    string attribute = preferencename.ToString ();
    doc = new XmlDocument ();
    doc.Load (fs);
}
XmlNode user = doc.SelectSingleNode ("//Users/User[@Name = '" + username + "']");
XmlNode pref = user.SelectSingleNode("Pref");
pref.Attributes[attribute].Value = newvalue;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream (filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    doc.Save (fs);
}
```

You can replace the second part by:

```
doc.Save (filepath);
```

Comment: This helped some: I got past the first using block but it failed trying to load the second one.

Comment: What if you replace the second `using` part by `doc.Save(filepath)`?

Comment: code blows up :P It caused the same sharing violation but it wasn't caught by the try block, so the xml data disappeared and the next read caused an unhanded error because there was no data

Comment: Hmm. Then I think your program still has the file open somewhere. In *Linux* you can run `lsof -p pid` with `pid` the process id to list the files that are open by a process. Perhaps you can thus check if the file is open.

Comment: I like the linux (used to run Ubuntu) but on Macbook now. I've tried several things to see if file was in use by a process or open somewhere but haven't had much luck. Does lsof work on Mac and if so what is the best way to use it?

Comment: I think so, most Linux commands are supported by the Mac terminal. You thus need to run the program (perhaps without setting the preference file), then determine the process id and then run lsof to check the open files.

Comment: My term skills are rusty. Could you explain this in more depth or point me to a place that does?

Comment: I piped lsof through grep to search for the file both during and after execution and got nothing on it.